# Usage of "is" in messages

Tags: grammaticality, british-english, writing-advice

Which among the two below is correct?

Usage Data unavailable.

OR

Usage Data is unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct, mainly.

Data is the plural of Datum, a single piece of information, so technically speaking the second line would be more accurately stated "Usage Data are unavailable", but to all intents and purposes, no one uses Data in the plural.

However, if you are including the verb with the second line, you might want to balance it by using a definite article: The Usage Data is unavailable.

My preference would be to use the first if you are trying to be concise, such as in a chart or a program variable, or the second in writing if you want to be more verbose.